# How to use a MacMini and its monitor as a secondary monitor for a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, networking, macbook, multiple-monitors

I found Synergy extends my keyboard and touchpad so I can seamlessly control the MacMini from my MacBook Pro, but that isn't quite what I want.

I have a MacMini connected to 40+ inch HDTV as a media system.  I'm looking for a way to use that 40+ inch HDTV wirelessly, through the MacMini, as a secondary monitor for the MacBook Pro.

Are their any tools that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html).

Comment: Thanks, I settled on ScreenRecycler.  I had to upgrade my wireless router to make it usable.  The developer encourages using it on a wired network, but that isn't practical for my home.  Also, I initially purchased his bundle that included ScreenRecycler and JollyFastVNC.  I found that OSX's built-in vnc service was remarkably faster, yielding smoother window movements and no pixelation at all.  However, I also learned that you can use JollyFastVNC with ScreenRecycler without having to purchase it, so it's a good deal.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the accept! Glad it helped, even though the amount of data required an upgrade. Good to know.